# Combine skin material to two elements without a visible seam

Tags: models, 3dsmax, materials

Software used: 3ds max 2015 and Photoshop CC 2014.

[image: screenshot illustrating the problem]

I have two elements of the head, the "FaceHead" and "UpperHead". I used unwrap UVW for both elements and used Photoshop to add a skin color (eye and lips for "FaceHead") and the same skin color for "UpperHead". I created an image for both elements in Photoshop and added the image to the elements using the Material Editor (with Bitmap option). The problem is, that there is a visible seam between the 2 elements, although I used the same color for both. Is there a solution to solve this?

What I tried:

- Used of MaterialByElement
- Used of different color
- Extend to 2 pixel from the border using Photoshop when applying Paint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is most likely the cause of you splitting the mesh in two parts. The normals at the cut are pointing into different directions (because of triangle orientations) and thus you get a visible seam.

Usually you don't split your geometry for UV unwrapping. What you want to do is mark edges as "seams" so that the UV gets cut at these seams.

Here's a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ouHLM490rL4#t=224) that should explain the necessary steps to mark an edge as a seam.

Comment: I can't select the end edges to be converted to seam,so i delete them and created new one and that solved the problem.